# Можно ли определить координаты населенного пункта по kladrID (Yandex maps)

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

Доброго времени суток!

Возможно ли определить координаты населенного пункта по kladrID в Yandex Maps?

Comment: Получаешь текстовый адрес по ID, скармливаешь Yandex Maps, надеешься на лучшее. PS. KLADR вообще-то умер. Как раз в Новый год...

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А какой аналог кладра посоветуешь использовать?

Comment: ФИАС https://fias.nalog.ru/FiasInfo

Comment: API Геокодера позволяет определить координаты по адресу, вот примеры и документация: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geocoder/doc/desc/examples/geocoder_examples-docpage/ . Обратите внимание на условия использования API: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/terms/index-docpage/?from=geocoder#conditions .